# Posting on facebook page without login from a php based website

Tags: php, facebook

I was wondering, is it possible to post on my facebook page from my website (PHP).
I want to post things automatically on my facebook page from my website when a user adds a record.
I have a website that has classified ads on it and I have hired few data entry guys to enter record in it from the website frontend. I want to post that entries on my facebook page.

Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: ^ but it will need the admin user to authenticate by logging in. if a user enters a record on my website how will it be posted on my business page ?

Comment: Yes, but only once (if you get an extended page access token).

Comment: Can someone explain it to me with a coding example ? I have been looking into facebook API since Thursday.. :( no luck